# как переместить мышь на неполный пиксель?

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть код:

```
Sleep(11);
mouse_event((0x0001), -3, 4, 0, 0);
Sleep(11);
mouse_event((0x0001), -3, 4, 0, 0);
Sleep(11);
mouse_event((0x0001), -3, 4, 0, 0);
Sleep(11);
mouse_event((0x0001), -3, 4, 0, 0);
Sleep(11);
```

Но проблема в том что,если я задам какой нибудь коэффициент для какой нибудь оси,типа 1.2,то произойдет ошибка округления.Я понимаю,что чисто физически невозможно переместить мышь на пол пикселя,так как это "базис".Но может быть есть какие нибудь способы переместить мышь например не на -3 ,а на -3.6?

P.S уточнение.
Программа представляет из себя макрос для контроля отдачи в игре.У меня функция которая вызывается когда мы нажимаем ЛКМ,и в ней перемещения записаны таким образом,что отдача оружия в игре гасится и как будто ее нету:

```
void ak47()
{
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), -3, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), -3, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), -3, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), -3, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), -3, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), -3, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), -2, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), -2, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), -2, 3, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), -2, 3, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), 1, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), 1, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), 1, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 mouse_event((0x0001), 1, 4, 0, 0);
}
```

Но проблема в том,что в некоторых случаях,отдача может меняться на несколько процентов,в таких случаях идеально было бы умножать смещения на процент/100,то так нельзя,в этом то и проблема.

Comment: Храните и накапливайте перемещение отдельно от вывода.

Comment: проблема в том что у меня тысяча таких ивентов,этот кусочек в примере это малая часть,и они идут не по одной прямой,по этому не получится взять накопить перемещение и раскидать по этим ивентам

Comment: приведите больше контекста, т.е. как и зачем будут выполняться выши mouse_event, т.к. на данный момент таких способов нет, координаты мыши представляют собой целые числа

Comment: добавил уточнение

Comment: еще уточнение, у вас первый ивент двигает мышь на 3 пикселя влево, потом еще один на 3 пикселя. Если вы добавляете ваш коэй-т, то получится два движения на 3.6 и 3.6 пикселя, т.е. суммарно на 7, верно? а сейчас получается суммарно на 6, т.к. числа целые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, как и писал @Kromster, используйте накопление

```
void ak47()
{
 double coefficient = 1.2;
 double step1 = -3.0 * coefficient;
 double step2 = -2.0 * coefficient;
 double step3 = 1.0 * coefficient;

 double current = 0;

 Sleep(11);
 current += step1; // current ~ -3.6; mouse moved -3px
 mouse_event((0x0001), (long)current, 4, 0, 0);
 Sleep(11);
 current -= (long)step1; // current ~ -0.6
 current += step1; // current ~ -4.2; mouse moved -4px
 mouse_event((0x0001), (long)current, 4, 0, 0);
 ...
}
```